# c# itextsharp pdf image align left text right

Tags: c#, itext

I am trying to do pdf generation using itextsharp.pdf but i'm having allignment issues. I'd like picture to be on the left side, and text on right (they should be on the same line).

I have tried:

```
jpeg.Alignment = Image.TEXTWRAP | Image.ALIGN_LEFT;
doc.Add(jpeg);
Paragraph paragraph2 = new Paragraph(new Phrase(content,PDFUtilsFonts.baseFontNormal));
paragraph2.Alignment = Element.ALIGN_JUSTIFIED;
doc.Add(paragraph2);
```

If i change Image.ALIGN_LEFT to Image.ALIGN_RIGHT then it works, but is is opposite of what i need.

Comment: Put the image and the text in two different cells of a table.

Comment: Hi Bruno, thanks for quick reply. The thing is, sometimes the text is really long, and i'd like to use this method since it auto generates new page. For a bit more detail, i need pdf generation that generates appropriate picture but only on first page, and if the text is too long, it's splits into multiple pages.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - i guess there is no way around this?

Comment: Only if you use irregular columns, but I don't have the time to explain that concept right now.